# What does "be an insult to the fabric of space/time itself" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He became a scheduling black hole, missing meetings and deadlines as
>   if they were an insult to the fabric of space/time itself.

I know the meanings of the words, I know the phrases "black hole" and "fabric of space/time" refer to the Einstein Relativity Theory. But I can not get the meaning of the sentence.

So, Could you please explain it to me?

The fuller text is:

> The surgeon cut the tumor out, and Elliot went home. He went back to
>   work. He went back to his family and friends. Everything seemed fine
>   and normal. Then things went horribly wrong. Elliot’s work performance
>   suffered. Tasks that were once a breeze to him now required mountains
>   of concentration and effort. Simple decisions, such as whether to use
>   a blue pen or a black pen, would consume him for hours. He would make
>   basic errors and leave them unfixed for weeks. He became a scheduling
>   black hole, missing meetings and deadlines **as if they were an insult
>   to the fabric of space/time itself**.

Comment: Did you just create the `add` tag for this question?

Comment: It was edited...

Answer (score 1):

This a rather hyperbolic use of a metaphor. One meaning of [insult](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insult} is "injury to the body or one of its parts". This meaning is normally confined to  medical contexts. Here it is first being extended to a very general context, and then used in a figurative way. The suggestion seems to be that "meetings and deadlines" might somehow injure the very fabric of space-time, and so Elliot avoided them with a passion. In short, this actually means that "Elliot missed all his meetings and deadlines".

Answer (score 1):

"the fabric of space/time" is a ***very grand thing***. Perhaps, the grandest thing in physics as it is about things being held together in the universe. One cannot actually "insult" the fabric of space/time.

Here, the author is using **hyperbole** (exaggeration).a common literary device,  to make his point.

The character was "missing meetings and deadlines" as if these meetings and deadlines were really bad news. As if **they were insults to grandest thing in the universe**, the fabric of space/time.

Hyperbolic exaggeration: That professor has a gnat's brain.